# Static JSON Array push to results from API

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the following snippet which returns the JSON Response as mentioned below:

```
respArray = []
      respArray = respBody.classifiers
      respBody = respArray
      if (respBody.length > 0) {
        respBody = applyPagination(respBody, reqParams.filter, options)
      }
```

The response is like:

```
[
{
    "classifier_id": "improper",
    "name": "improper",
    "owner": "",
    "status": "failed",
    "core_ml_enabled": true,
    "explanation": "",
    "created": "2019-07-04T14:28:37.402Z",
    "classes": [
        {
            "class": "impropertest"
        }
    ],
    "updated": "2019-07-04T14:28:37.402Z"
},
{
    "classifier_id": "improper",
    "name": "improper",
    "owner": "",
    "status": "failed",
    "core_ml_enabled": true,
    "explanation": "",
    "created": "2019-07-05T08:31:55.463Z",
    "classes": [
        {
            "class": "impropertest"
        }
    ],
    "updated": "2019-07-05T08:31:55.463Z"
}]
```

I have a static JSON like below which i want to append to the response from the API.

Sample Static JSON:

```
 "defaultClassifiers":{
"classifiers": [
  {
    "classifier_id": "general",
    "name": "general",
    "status": "ready",
    "owner": "",
    "created": "",
    "updated": "",
    "classes": [
      {
        "class": "general"
      }
    ],
    "core_ml_enabled": false
  },
  {
    "classifier_id": "explicit",
    "name": "explicit",
    "status": "ready",
    "owner": "",
    "created": "",
    "updated": "",
    "classes": [
      {
        "class": "explicit"
      }
    ],
    "core_ml_enabled": false
  },
  {
    "classifier_id": "food",
    "name": "food",
    "status": "ready",
    "owner": "",
    "created": "",
    "updated": "",
    "classes": [
      {
        "class": "food"
      }
    ],
    "core_ml_enabled": false
  }
]}
```

To achieve this I am trying something like:

```
respArray = []
      var defaultClassifiers = constants.defaultClassifiers.classifiers
      respArray.push(defaultClassifiers,respBody.classifiers)
      respBody = respArray
      if (respBody.length > 0) {
        respBody = applyPagination(respBody, reqParams.filter, options)
      }
```

The output i have is:

```
[
{
    "0": {
        "classifier_id": "general",
        "name": "general",
        "status": "ready",
        "owner": "",
        "created": "",
        "updated": "",
        "classes": [
            {
                "class": "general"
            }
        ],
        "core_ml_enabled": false
    },
    "1": {
        "classifier_id": "explicit",
        "name": "explicit",
        "status": "ready",
        "owner": "",
        "created": "",
        "updated": "",
        "classes": [
            {
                "class": "explicit"
            }
        ],
        "core_ml_enabled": false
    },
    "2": {
        "classifier_id": "food",
        "name": "food",
        "status": "ready",
        "owner": "",
        "created": "",
        "updated": "",
        "classes": [
            {
                "class": "food"
            }
        ],
        "core_ml_enabled": false
    }
},
{
    "0": {
        "classifier_id": "link_877889562",
        "name": "link",
        "status": "ready",
        "owner": "",
        "created": "2019-07-05T04:10:06.457Z",
        "updated": "2019-07-05T04:10:06.457Z",
        "classes": [
            {
                "class": "classcreatezip1"
            }
        ],
        "core_ml_enabled": true
    },
    "1": {
        "classifier_id": "classifer1807",
        "name": "classifer1807",
        "status": "ready",
        "owner": "",
        "created": "2019-07-25T10:43:00.012Z",
        "updated": "2019-07-25T10:43:00.012Z",
        "classes": [
            {
                "class": "class18"
            }
        ],
        "core_ml_enabled": true
    }]
```

I was expecting output like:

```
[
  {
    "classifier_id": "general",
    "name": "general",
    "status": "ready",
    "owner": "",
    "created": "",
    "updated": "",
    "classes": [
      {
        "class": "general"
      }
    ],
    "core_ml_enabled": false
  },
  {
    "classifier_id": "explicit",
    "name": "explicit",
    "status": "ready",
    "owner": "",
    "created": "",
    "updated": "",
    "classes": [
      {
        "class": "explicit"
      }
    ],
    "core_ml_enabled": false
  },
  {
    "classifier_id": "food",
    "name": "food",
    "status": "ready",
    "owner": "",
    "created": "",
    "updated": "",
    "classes": [
      {
        "class": "food"
      }
    ],
    "core_ml_enabled": false
  },
  {
    "classifier_id": "improper",
    "name": "improper",
    "owner": "",
    "status": "failed",
    "core_ml_enabled": true,
    "explanation": "",
    "created": "2019-07-04T14:28:37.402Z",
    "classes": [
        {
            "class": "impropertest"
        }
    ],
    "updated": "2019-07-04T14:28:37.402Z"
},
{
    "classifier_id": "improper",
    "name": "improper",
    "owner": "",
    "status": "failed",
    "core_ml_enabled": true,
    "explanation": "",
    "created": "2019-07-05T08:31:55.463Z",
    "classes": [
        {
            "class": "impropertest"
        }
    ],
    "updated": "2019-07-05T08:31:55.463Z"
}]
```

As far as i know push add the object to the array which is not happening. And adding the keys 0,1 etc which is strange. What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, I'm not sure what `applyPagination` does, but I'm going to assume it takes an array of classifiers and returns a filtered array of classifiers based on the other parameters you pass in.

In order to prepend the default classifiers to your response classifiers, you can do:

```
const defaultClassifiers = constants.defaultClassifiers.classifiers;
const responseClassifiers = respBody.classifiers;
let respBody = defaultClassifiers.concat(responseClassifiers);
if (respBody.length > 0) {
    respBody = applyPagination(respBody, reqParams.filter, options)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not entering objects into your JSON, but an array, where each index holds an object, which in turns holds properties.

The numbers are array indices.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve it with `es6` copy operator.

```
 const defaultArr = [
  {
    classifier_id: 'general',
    name: 'general',
    status: 'ready',
    owner: '',
    created: '',
    updated: '',
    classes: [
      {
        class: 'general',
      },
    ],
    core_ml_enabled: false,
  },
  {
    classifier_id: 'explicit',
    name: 'explicit',
    status: 'ready',
    owner: '',
    created: '',
    updated: '',
    classes: [
      {
        class: 'explicit',
      },
    ],
    core_ml_enabled: false,
  },
  {
    classifier_id: 'food',
    name: 'food',
    status: 'ready',
    owner: '',
    created: '',
    updated: '',
    classes: [
      {
        class: 'food',
      },
    ],
    core_ml_enabled: false,
  },
];

const result = [{
  classifier_id: 'improper',
  name: 'improper',
  owner: '',
  status: 'failed',
  core_ml_enabled: true,
  explanation: '',
  created: '2019-07-04T14:28:37.402Z',
  classes: [
    {
      class: 'impropertest',
    },
  ],
  updated: '2019-07-04T14:28:37.402Z',
},
{
  classifier_id: 'improper',
  name: 'improper',
  owner: '',
  status: 'failed',
  core_ml_enabled: true,
  explanation: '',
  created: '2019-07-05T08:31:55.463Z',
  classes: [
    {
      class: 'impropertest',
    },
  ],
  updated: '2019-07-05T08:31:55.463Z',
}];

const finalArray = [...defaultArr, ...result];
```

```js
const defaultArr = [
  {
classifier_id: 'general',
name: 'general',
status: 'ready',
owner: '',
created: '',
updated: '',
classes: [
  {
    class: 'general',
  },
],
core_ml_enabled: false,
  },
  {
classifier_id: 'explicit',
name: 'explicit',
status: 'ready',
owner: '',
created: '',
updated: '',
classes: [
  {
    class: 'explicit',
  },
],
core_ml_enabled: false,
  },
  {
classifier_id: 'food',
name: 'food',
status: 'ready',
owner: '',
created: '',
updated: '',
classes: [
  {
    class: 'food',
  },
],
core_ml_enabled: false,
  },
];

const result = [{
  classifier_id: 'improper',
  name: 'improper',
  owner: '',
  status: 'failed',
  core_ml_enabled: true,
  explanation: '',
  created: '2019-07-04T14:28:37.402Z',
  classes: [
{
  class: 'impropertest',
},
  ],
  updated: '2019-07-04T14:28:37.402Z',
},
{
  classifier_id: 'improper',
  name: 'improper',
  owner: '',
  status: 'failed',
  core_ml_enabled: true,
  explanation: '',
  created: '2019-07-05T08:31:55.463Z',
  classes: [
{
  class: 'impropertest',
},
  ],
  updated: '2019-07-05T08:31:55.463Z',
}];

const finalArray = [...defaultArr, ...result];
console.log(finalArray);
```

Using this you got your desired Output.
Happy Coding :)